# how to display employee that doesn't belong to department (SQL)

Tags: sql, database, count, foreign-keys, where-clause

how to write SQL to display How many employees doesn't belong to any department?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select count(*)
from employees
where deptno is null;
```

Comment: i want the difference between both tables (employees and department)

Comment: This answers the question that you asked:  "How many employees doesn't belong to any department?"

Answer (score 0):

That's basic filtering:

```
select count(*) cnt
from employees
where depno is null
```

That gives you the count of employees that are not assigned to a department. If you want to list the corresponding rows:

```
select *
from employees
where depno is null
```

Comment: but i want it in both tables (employees and department)

Comment: @Judy: you don't need the department table to get the result you want. There are two employees without a department, and that's what the query brings.